# "The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance." error for non-transfer func

Tags: arrays, smart-contract-wallets, payable

This is my first post on this stack exchange site and it comes after a couple of hours of banging my head against this error's wall.

In short, I am currently going through a solidity course and one of the projects I am working on is a "shared wallet" concept with different roles (in my example below *admin, family, approved spender*), an allowance/role and a concept of "remaining balance" for each address that has at least 1 role assigned (i.e member).

The problem I am facing and which I cannot understand is why do I get this error *"Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."* when running the *"SetAllowance"* function?
**What I cannot understand is why is the notion of "payable" invoked in the error returned when running a function that does not include any "payable" like method (i.e transfer, call, send)?!**

My code below:

```
//Contract based on [https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract SharedWallet is Ownable, AccessControl {
using SafeMath for uint256;

event BalanceReceived (address indexed _from, uint256 _amount);
event AmountSpent (address indexed _by, address indexed _to, uint256 _amount);

bytes32 public constant FAMILY_ROLE = keccak256("FAMILY");
bytes32 public constant ApprovedSpender_ROLE = keccak256("ApprovedSpender");

mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public allowance;
mapping(address => uint256) public remainingBalance;

address payable[] internal AllFamilyAcc;
address payable[] internal AllAppSpendersAcc;

constructor () public {
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    allowance[FAMILY_ROLE] = 1 ether;
    allowance[ApprovedSpender_ROLE] = 2 ether;
}

modifier onlyAdmin() {
    require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender));
    _;
}
modifier OnlyMembers() {
    require(hasRole(ApprovedSpender_ROLE, msg.sender) || hasRole(FAMILY_ROLE, msg.sender) || hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender));
    _;
}

function SetAllowance(uint256 _FamilyAmount, uint256 _AppSpenderAmount)
    public payable
    {
    for (uint i=0; i<=AllFamilyAcc.length; i++) {        
          remainingBalance[AllFamilyAcc[i]] += _FamilyAmount;
      }

    
    for (uint i=0; i<=AllAppSpendersAcc.length; i++) { 
          remainingBalance[AllAppSpendersAcc[i]] += _AppSpenderAmount;
      }
    }

function addFamilyMember(address payable _account)
    public virtual
    {
        require(!hasRole(FAMILY_ROLE, _account),"Already a family member!");
        grantRole(FAMILY_ROLE, _account);
        remainingBalance[_account] = allowance[FAMILY_ROLE];
        AllFamilyAcc.push(payable(_account));
    }

function addApprovedSpender(address payable _account)
    public virtual
    {
        require(!hasRole(ApprovedSpender_ROLE, _account),"Already an approved spender!");
        grantRole(ApprovedSpender_ROLE, _account);
        remainingBalance[_account]=allowance[ApprovedSpender_ROLE];
        AllAppSpendersAcc.push(payable(_account));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the function from which you have this error?

Comment: Can you add the code calling the function?

Comment: the function throwing this error is the "SetAllowance" function (already in the description but you have to slightly scroll down). Sorry for the amount of lines added but thought I would include everything that is relevant to this function for context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to change these `for` conditions in `SetAllowance()` function:

```
for (uint i=0; i <= AllFamilyAcc.length; i++){
  ...
}

for (uint i=0; i <= AllAppSpendersAcc.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```

in this way:

```
function SetAllowance(uint256 _FamilyAmount, uint256 _AppSpenderAmount) public payable {
        for (uint i=0; i < AllFamilyAcc.length; i++) {
            remainingBalance[AllFamilyAcc[i]] += _FamilyAmount;
        }

        for (uint i=0; i < AllAppSpendersAcc.length; i++) {
            remainingBalance[AllAppSpendersAcc[i]] += _AppSpenderAmount;
        }
    }
```

This because, if AllFamilyAcc length is 3 items (address0, address1, address2) with this condition `i <= AllFamilyAcc.length` you iterate until i=3 but in your array doesn't exists an element at index 3 and then compiler give you this error. When you change this condition  in `i < AllFamilyAcc.length`, last iteration'll be 2 and (in this example) last value at index=2 is address2. The same reasoning is for AllAppSpendersAcc cycle.

Comment: This was it, thanks a lot for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

I think it have to be payable because the `AllAppSpendersAcc[i]` is of type `address payable` and since you are using payble address the compiler asumes that this function will transfer Ether around. You can store the payable addresses as `address` and whe you need them to be payable you can cast them like that:

```
    address adr = 0x.........;
    payable(adr).transfer(...);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see what the suggested solution is. 
The "SetAllowance" function is already defined as "payable" and before posting the question here I guess I tried all the possible combinations. What strikes me is why this function throws a "payable" related error when it does not invoke any payable related method; it just features a "balance" addition.

P.S: If you copy paste the code in Remix, add 2 random addresses to each one of the groups and then run the function, the error should be visible.

Comment: It is because `AllFamilyAcc` is of type `address payable[]` and it is used in your function which make the whole function payable

Comment: Excuse me, I appreciate you taking the time but the answer does not help in solving the problem. As you can see in the description, everything (i.e the 2 address arrays as well as the "SetAllowance" function) is set as "payable", however I still get the error. I have also tried running the function by removing the "payable" definition from both the address arrays + the function but surprisingly the same error gets thrown out. 
Would appreciate a precise answer as to what needs to be modified to avoid getting the error mentioned in the description.